# JavaFX - Why are ChoiceBoxes parametrized?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, javafx

I'm studying JavaFX and I'm seeing about ChoiceBoxes. The question is simple: Why are choice boxes parametrized if they are supposed to carry heterogeneous data?

A problem caused by this is the impossibility of implement the example of the oficial guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/choice-box.htm.

I have this code:

```
final String[] greetings = new String[] { "Hello", "Hola", "Olá"};
final ChoiceBox cb2 = new ChoiceBox(
        FXCollections.observableArrayList("English", "Español", "Portuguese"));
final Label theText = new Label(greetings[0]);

cb2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) ->
       theText.setText(greetings[newValue.intValue()])
);
```

The compiler reports the lambda is not valid because it has incompatible types with the CheckBox class, that holds the String type, even it's not being parametrized. But if I parametrize CheckBox with `<Object>` I will need to cast the `newValue` to Number type, and in Runtime I get a `ClassCastException` saying it cannot cast String to number.

Why do ChoiceBox class locks you to a unique type available? Choicebox should hold on heterogeneous data.

Also: With this problem, how would I implement the oficial guide example?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are expecting the `selectedItem` property to be the index of the selected item: it isn't: it's the actual item itself. So if you're putting `String`s in there, you register a `ChangeListener<String>` with the selected item.

The index is the `selectedIndex` property. So you can do

```
final String[] greetings = new String[] { "Hello", "Hola", "Olá"};
final ChoiceBox<String> cb2 = new ChoiceBox<String>(
        FXCollections.observableArrayList("English", "Español", "Portuguese"));
final Label theText = new Label(greetings[0]);

cb2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, String newValue) ->
       System.out.println("Selected language is: "+newValue)
);

cb2.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldIndex, Number newIndex) -> 
       theText.setText(greetings[newValue.intValue()])
);
```

As to the question "why are they parametrized", it's so that you can declare the data type that's there, and then retrieve the correct type. If your `ComboBox` is truly heterogeneous (i.e. it contains mixed data types), then the best you can do is declare it to be the most specific common superclass of all the data in there. (You probably want to ask if this is a good design choice.)

So for example:

```
ChoiceBox<Object> mixedChoices = new ChoiceBox<>();
// Put any Objects in there:
mixedChoices.getItems().addAll("One", new Integer(2), new Double(3.0));

mixedChoices.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends Object> ov, Object oldSelection, Object newSelection) -> 
        // compiler will only let me use Object here, but of course that makes sense, as I have no idea 
        // what object is selected....
        System.out.println(newSelection.toString())
);
```

But a better (IMHO) approach is to use appropriate object types in a homogeneous `ChoiceBox`. I would implement the example as

```
ChoiceBox<Locale> languages = new ChoiceBox<>();
languages.getItems().addAll(Locale.ENGLISH, new Locale("es"), new Locale("pt"));
languages.setConverter(new StringConverter<Locale>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Locale l) {
        return l.getDisplayLanguage(l);
    }
    @Override
    public Locale fromString(String language) {
        // not really needed, but...
        return Locale.forLanguageTag(language);
    }
});

languages.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (ObservableValue<? extends Locale> ov, Locale oldValue, Locale newValue) -> {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", newValue);
        theText.setText(rb.getString("greeting"));
});
```

Without parametrization, it would be

```
ChoiceBox languages = new ChoiceBox();
languages.getItems().addAll(Locale.ENGLISH, ...);
```

But now the compiler has no way of knowing we put into `Locale`'s into the choice box, so we are forced to downcast:

```
languages.getSelectionModel().addListener(
    (ObservableValue ov, Object oldChoice, Object newChoice) -> {
        // hmm, I know I put Locales in there, even though the complier doesn't:
        Locale languageChoice = (Locale) newChoice ;
        // etc
});
```

and of course the problem now is that if I make a coding error and put the wrong thing in the `ChoiceBox`, it is only caught at runtime. With the parameterized version it's caught at compile time. This is basically the way things were done in Swing, and is a very legacy (pre JDK5) coding style.

Comment: Yes, I just got it. Just a method mistake. Neverthless, the first question remains: Why CheckBoxes are parametrized?

Comment: Great example. But, it would make more sense if ChoiceBox were some kind of structure data. So, the question of type safety in retrieving the elements of the ChoiceBox would come. But, ChoiceBox is a graphical element! In your implementation: If you wanted to add Separators to create separate classes of options in your ChoiceBox?

Comment: The thing you are choosing in the `ChoiceBox` is some kind of structure data. That's the type you're specifying: you're not specifying a type of graphical element. (E.g. in my example, `Locale` is not a graphical type: neither is `String`, from your example.) Even with separators, you are choosing a single value; so there really should be only one type in there. (The way they implemented separators in `ChoiceBox` is woeful though: that is a blatant mix of UI types and data types.)